# How to call block function in CMS page?

Tags: orders, blocks, cms-pages, magento2.4

Version: Magento 2.4 EE

I want to show the Recently Ordered Items Block in CMS page but when I call the block in page, the block is not displaying as expected and the page is empty.

In CMS page, my code is as follows

```
{{block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Recent" template="Magento_Sales::order/recent.phtml"}}
```

The way which I have called the block is a right one?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
{{block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Recent" template="Magento_Sales::order/recent.phtml"}}
```

Your code is right. please check with cache flush and also check that you are logged in user.

If you still getting issue then check log files in developer mode.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Now I'm able to call the block. Can you please give me idea to make this work https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/324741/how-to-show-the-static-block-only-for-logged-in-customers-globally