# How to show the static block only for logged in customers globally?

Tags: magento2, blocks, phtml

I have created static block in admin panel and want to show that block only for logged in customers. I have tried it via creating the module and in template file I have written a condition to show the block for logged in customers but how can I make globally and not for specific page. For example, If I call that block in cms page that time as well the condition has to work.

```
<?php if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) { ?>
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()
->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
->setBlockId('testblock')
->toHtml();
?>
<?php } ?>
```

Please guide

Comment: Do have you try to call template file in default.xml?

Comment: @payal patel yes, I did try.     <referenceContainer name="content">  
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="testblock" as="testblock" template="Ecomm_CustomBlock::index/index.phtml">
          </block>
    </referenceContainer>

Comment: is the way I have called the template referring to block is right?

Comment: Kindly use this please,
<referenceContainer name="content"><block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="testblock" as="testblock" template="Ecomm_CustomBlock::index/index.phtml"> </block></referenceContainer>

Comment: thanks. I will check and let you know

Comment: @payal patel, I have tried with the code you suggested but still the condition is only working for the specific template. What i did is I just called the block in CMS page and the block is displaying without login as well. Please help

Comment: Do you just want to cms_page_view?

Comment: Yes, in cms page there are some banners, we need to hide banner before login.

Comment: `index.phtml` this template file is your custom template file?

Comment: yes, its the custom phtml file

Comment: Here, your issue is customer logged in session. Please make one function in helper for customer loggedin with use flag. After call helper in phtml template and call function in this with condition. I think it's working for you.

Use phtml template in `cms_page_view.xml` file

Comment: customer session condition which I have written is working for all the places except cms page which I want to show the block.